# How does the Postgres systemd unit file determine what version of Postgres to run?

Tags: postgresql, systemd

This is mainly a question out of curiosity. I was going through the Postgres systemd unit files to get a feel for what can be done with systemd. Postgres has two systemd unit files. One that is used in place of a systemd target:

```
# systemd service for managing all PostgreSQL clusters on the system. This
# service is actually a systemd target, but we are using a service since
# targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL RDBMS

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=on

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The second unit file is a template parameterized by on the Postgres version. It specifies it will be ran before the other unit file by using `Before=postgresql.service`:

```
# systemd service template for PostgreSQL clusters. The actual instances will
# be called "postgresql@version-cluster", e.g. "postgresql@9.3-main". The
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
# (%I breaks for cluster names containing dashes.)

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
ConditionPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
PartOf=postgresql.service
ReloadPropagatedFrom=postgresql.service
Before=postgresql.service

[Service]
Type=forking
# @: use "postgresql@%i" as process name
ExecStart=@/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster postgresql@%i --skip-systemctl-redirect %i start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect -m fast %i stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect %i reload
PIDFile=/var/run/postgresql/%i.pid
SyslogIdentifier=postgresql@%i
# prevent OOM killer from choosing the postmaster (individual backends will
# reset the score to 0)
OOMScoreAdjust=-900
# restarting automatically will prevent "pg_ctlcluster ... stop" from working,
# so we disable it here. Also, the postmaster will restart by itself on most
# problems anyway, so it is questionable if one wants to enable external
# automatic restarts.
#Restart=on-failure
# (This should make pg_ctlcluster stop work, but doesn't:)
#RestartPreventExitStatus=SIGINT SIGTERM

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

What I can't figure out is how systemd determines what versions of Postgres to run when I run `systemctl start postgresql`. When I look at the dependencies of `postgresql.service` I see there is a specific instance of the template, 9.5-main, that is a dependency:

```
> systemctl list-dependencies postgresql

postgresql.service
● ├─postgresql@9.5-main.service
● ├─postgresql@9.5-main.service
● ├─system.slice
● └─sysinit.target
●   ├─apparmor.service
●   ├─brltty.service
●   ├─console-setup.service
●   ├─dev-hugepages.mount
●   ├─dev-mqueue.mount
●   ├─friendly-recovery.service
●   ├─keyboard-setup.service
●   ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
●   ├─lvm2-lvmetad.socket
●   ├─lvm2-lvmpolld.socket
●   ├─lvm2-monitor.service
●   ├─plymouth-read-write.service
●   ├─plymouth-start.service
●   ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
●   ├─resolvconf.service
●   ├─setvtrgb.service
●   ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
```

I can't find any file that specifies that Postgres 9.5 should be used. There aren't any other Postgres unit files and none of the other files mention Postgres at all. This is on Ubuntu 16.04 with systemd 229 and Postgres 9.5 (installed through `sudo apt-get install postgresql`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From : https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

```
"%i"    Instance name   For instantiated units: this is the string between the "@" character and the suffix of the unit name.
```

Filename is postgres@9.3-main.service so `%i = 9.3-main`

Update :

An instance file is usually created as a symbolic link to the template file, with the link name including the instance identifier

```
file /run/systemd/generator/postgresql.service.wants/postgresql@9.4-main.service
/run/systemd/generator/postgresql.service.wants/postgresql@9.4-main.service: symbolic link to /lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service
```

Comment: Where do you see that a file with the name `postgres@9.3-main.service`? As mentioned in the question, I don't see any unit files besides `postgresql.service` and `postgresql@.service`. I checked in both `/lib/systemd/system` and `/etc/systemd/system`.

Comment: See details to understand where postgres@9.3-main.service is stored.

Comment: Ok. I see the file now. I'll take a look at understanding the `/run/systemd/generator` directory. Thanks!